# ASP.NET MVC3: Custom Validation Messages for invalid datatype

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an account field, which has a dropdown box of accounts, which underlying, sends off the account number.

So when nothing is entered, the validation message says "The field AccNo must be a number." or "The AccNo field is required." The default option sometimes triggers the number type validation as it has no number assigned.

Is there any way I can change this to simply say, "Please select an Account", for cases where nothing is entered AND when it assumes a number isnt entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could decorate the property you are binding your dropdownlist to with the `[Required]` attribute which will enforce the user to select a value:

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select an Account")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItems> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model AccountViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.AccountNumber,
    Model.Accounts,
    "-- select an account --"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you completely, but can't you just use the annotation:

```
[Range(0, 99999,ErrorMessage = "Please select an Account")]
```

on the field in your model ?
(I used the Range validation only for the example)